# Redirect French homepage (and only FR home page) to English home page

Tags: .htaccess, 301-redirect, mod-alias

Using the `.htaccess` file, I would like to redirect `www.example.com/fr/` to `www.example.com/` but not other French pages that have the `/fr/` root (e.g. `www.example.com/fr/page-name`)

I've tried using `Redirect 301 /fr/ https://example.com/` but that redirects all the French pages to the English versions, which I don't want.

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> Redirect 301 /fr/ https://example.com/
> ```

The mod_alias `Redirect` directive is prefix-matching, so it redirects everything that simply starts `/fr/` and copies everything after the match onto the end of the target URL. It's great for redirecting entire URL branches (or entire sites), but not for specific URLs.

To redirect a specific URL you need to use `RedirectMatch`, which matches against a regex, instead of simple prefix-matching.

For example:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/fr/$ https://example.com/
```

Note that if you have existing mod_rewrite directives (ie. `RewriteRule`) then you may need to use (or may be preferable to use) mod_rewrite instead here.

Reference:

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch

Comment: Perfect, this works! Thanks!